# My button is not responding to my event listener?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code. I am trying to generate a random hex color that will replace the background color when my button is clicked but I can't get it to work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Color Changer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <button id="newColor">Click Me</button>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
const btn = document.getElementById("newColor");

btn.addEventListener("click", function onClick(event) {
    let randColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randColor;
});
```

Comment: your code works perfectly. Please check - https://jsfiddle.net/8dcbpzav/

Comment: your HTML doesn't load any javascript ... how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Bravo It's working now thank you, I had to add the script source in my HTML file.

Comment: it does help to load javascript if you want to run javascript

Answer (score 1):

1. include your js file to html file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Color Changer</title>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <button id="newColor">Click Me</button>
        </h1>
        // or include here
        //<script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. can use event [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) of js same as :

```
window.onload = function () {
    const btn = document.getElementById("newColor");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function onClick(event) {
        let randColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = randColor;
    });
};
```

3. can use jquery with  [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

the code is working is your js code is after the HTML tag?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("newColor");

btn.addEventListener("click", function onClick(event) {
    let randColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randColor;
});
```

```html
        <h1>
            <button id="newColor">Click Me</button>
        </h1>
```

Comment: the js code is in a separate js file

Comment: You just need to make sure that html is rendered first